# jQuery dynamically set <h3> in <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for (var i = 0; i < weekNo; i++) {
  $("<div>").attr({
    'id': "chart_div_" + i
  }).css({
    'border': '1px solid #ccc',
    'width': '750px',
    'height': '200px'
  }).appendTo("body");
  $("<br>").appendTo("body");
}
```

How do I set, for each generated div, a h3 tag with a text ?

Comment: You can try something like this, `$("<div><h1>"+your_dynamic_variable_goes_here+"</h1>").attr({ 'id': "chart_div_" + i }).css({ 'border': '1px solid #ccc', 'width': '750px', 'height': '200px' }).appendTo("body");`

Comment: As a sidenote, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment . If you append to the fragment and then append the fragment to the body once the loop finishes, you'll have a faster page. :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < weekNo; i++) {
    var div = $("<div>").attr({ 'id': "chart_div_" + i }).css({ 'border': '1px solid #ccc', 'width': '750px', 'height': '200px' }).appendTo("body");
    div.append('<h3>' + text + '</h3>');
    $("<br>").appendTo("body");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help!

```js
var weekNo = 5;

for (var i = 0; i < weekNo; i++) {

  var div = $("<div>").attr({
    'id': "chart_div_" + i
  }).text("Div " + i + " content here").css({
    'border': '1px solid #ccc',
    'width': '750px',
    'height': '200px'
  }).appendTo("body");

  $("<h3>").attr({
    'id': "h3_" + i
  }).text("Header " + i).prependTo(div);

  $("<br>").appendTo("body");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still no heading appearing... I'm using the divs to load different google charts from my web API and I wanna load some info about each chart in the heading... I've tried all the above answers, nothing appears.

@Pugazh

Comment: For `<h3>` try `.prependTo()`. Check the updated answer. If still an issue reproduce it in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/)